# Can I use Logitech ultrathin wireless keyboard for iPad also with my MacBook?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

This is the product, and it links to your iPad with Bluetooth:
http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/ultrathin-keyboard-cover

The question is whether one could also use it with other Mac devices such as MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can actually use it - I have it and used it at home before with different Apple devices.